# How to show Widget in Content Bottom part on home page in twenty sixteen theme

Tags: widgets, theme-twenty-sixteen

I am using twenty sixteen theme and home page is set to 'latest posts'. Sidebar is shown on home page but bottom widgets are not visible on home page. On a blog post page all of the widgets are visible.
How can I show bottom widgets on home page in twenty sixteen theme?

Homepage bottom -

[image]

Blog Post page bottom -

[image]

Comment: Can I purchase your username?

Comment: I'll fix this for your username.